# Passing and manipulating parameter from URL using JS

Tags: javascript, html, url, formatting, parameter-passing

Issue: Read the parameter from url and display in HTML after necessary formatting

Description:
URL: www.abc.com/test.html?name=Raj%20Sharma%20&%20Anjali%20Sharma

On Click event it should show the following:

Raj Sharma & Anjali Sharma

What I have till now is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getParameter(){
var param1var = getQueryVariable("name");
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = param1var;
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var vars = query.split("&");
for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
var pair = vars[i].split("=");
if (pair[0] == variable) {
return pair[1];
}
} 
alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getParameter()" id="continue">Click</a>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am really new in writing JS.

Answer (score 2):

This is enough to get that output:

```
 var query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1).split('=').pop());
```

> query: "Raj Sharma & Anjali Sharma"